# Different kind of Java EE projects

Tags: eclipse, ear, eclipse-wtp, jca, application-client

What is the different between different kind of Java EE projects in Eclipse WTP?

There are:

- Application Client Project
- Connector Project
- Enterprise Application Project
- Utility Project

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Quoting the *Chapter 5. Projects* of the [RAD v7, Programming Guide](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247501.html) (applies to Eclipse too):

> - **Application Client Project (J2EE)** — Guides the user through
>     creating an empty Application Client
>     project. Includes prompts for the
>     associated EAR project and a list of
>     facets applicable for J2EE Application
>     Client projects.
> - **Connector Project (J2EE)** — Guides the user through creating a
>     J2EE connector project, which includes
>     specifying the associated enterprise
>     application project and a set of
>     facets applicable to it.
> - **Enterprise Application Project (J2EE)** — Creates a new EAR project.
>     This includes options for creating
>     associated Web, EJB, and Application
>     Client projects.
> - **Utility Project (J2EE)** — Assists in the construction of a Java utility
>     library project which is associated
>     with an Enterprise Application
>     project. The product of such a project
>     is a JAR file that is available to the
>     resources within the Enterprise
>     project and is automatically wrapped
>     into the EAR file when it is exported.

This is detailed a few pages later:

> #### Enterprise Application project
>
> Enterprise Application projects contain the resources needed for enterprise
>   applications and can contain references to a combination of Web modules, EJB
>   modules, application client modules, resource adapter modules, utility Java
>   projects, and JAR files.
>
> These relationships can be specified when creating a new Enterprise Application
>   project through the wizard or through the project properties.
>
> For more information on developing J2EE enterprise applications, see
>   [Chapter 16, “Develop Web applications using EJBs” on page 719](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=NLu6AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA719&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false).
>
> #### J2EE Application Client project
>
> J2EE Application Client projects contain the resources needed for J2EE
>   application client modules. An application client module is used to contain a
>   fully-functioning client Java application (non-Web-based) that connects to and
>   uses the J2EE resources in a J2EE enterprise application and an application
>   server. By holding a reference to the associated enterprise application, it shares
>   information such as the Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) reference to
>   EJBs and data sources.
>
> #### Connector project
>
> A connector project contains the resources required for a J2EE resource adapter.
>   The wizard allows a set of facets (including the J2EE Connector Architecture
>   (JCA) version) and containing EAR file to be specified.

Short version: they are all wizards to create an Enterprise Application or its parts.

Comment: Application Client Project (J2EE) - Does this type of application run on server or this run as seperate application , and any use case of this kind of application will be really helpful